# How to get signal bars in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

How can I get the signal bars on iOS? I've read that it's impossible but there is an app in the appstore called Signals which does exactly what I want.

Comment: Without actually downloading the app and inspecting it, I'm going to guess it managed to slip some private API usage past Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (not with public APIs at least). That app Signals hasn't been updated for over 2 years. I just tried the app and it doesn't seem to be able to grab my signal data. Perhaps there used to be an API that grabs the signal that's no longer available in the later SDK. Either way, to the best of my knowledge, there's no way to reliably grab signal data.

One way to fake it I guess is to ping a reliable server (google for example) and figure out the round trip time when you have respective bars.

Comment: The application does it alone. It updates every 30 seconds submitting the signal to a server.